# Im trying to return a new class from a property getter, but I dont understand why one syntax works and another one with ternary operator does not

Tags: c#, properties, ternary

This is probably a simple C# question for somebody, who has been working in it for long enough. 
Can I do something like this

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then inside some other class I have something like this

```
    MyClass myClass;

    public MyClass MyProperty { get { return myClass ?? new    MyClass().SetName("myName"); } }
```

So  when I call Myproperty if it is null I want to just create a new one with a property set this way, I cannot use constructor on MyClass, instead I have few overloaded methods, that I call when MyClass is constructed.

This works

```
   public MyClass MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            myClass = myClass ?? new MyClass();
            myClass.SetName("myName");
            return myClass;
        }
    }
```

But I’m just curious why this does not, what is the difference because I don’t see any

```
public MyClass MyProperty 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return myClass ?? new    MyClass().SetName("myName"); 
   }
}
```

EDIT:

I just did this instead based on the opinions

```
public MyClass MyProperty 
{ 
   get 
   { 
            if (myClass == null)
            {
                myClass = new MyClass();
                myClass.SetName("myName);
            }
            return repository;
   }
 }
```

Another approach is to change MyClass to

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }
 }
```

and then use it like this

```
    MyClass myClass;
    public MyClass MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myClass ?? new MyClass().SetName("myName");
        }
    }
```

And Im going with it :0 
Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: Even if this worked (e.g. if you changed `SetName` to return `this`) they wouldn't do the same thing. Your second snippet would only call `SetName` if it created a new instance - your first snippet *always* calls `SetName`.

Comment: O yeah, you are right I actually did not see that the first snippet always sets calls the SetName, Now I need to actaully add more to it, I dont want to change the name is myClass is not null. Thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return type of `SetName` is void.

So `new MyClass().SetName("myName")` is `void`, not instance of `MyClass`.

**UPDATE**

To achieve your desired behaviour, you can change SetName to return `this`, and rewrite your `MyProperty` setter for example, to `return myClass ?? new MyClass().SetName("myName");`

Comment: So, is there anyway to set it up like this? I cannot do it via contructor because I want to be able to pass different contexts to it. After all it is not a big deal, because couple of more lines will do it, but if there is a way I'd like to know about it :) thanks

Comment: Use an `if` statement?

Comment: @adminSoftDK: Well, you can change `SetName` to return `this`, and rewrite your setter for `MyProperty` for example, to `return (myClass ?? new MyClass()).SetName("myName");`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Hi, thank you, this seems to compile :) i just need to run it to see whether it works. If you add is as answer I accept it, because this is the closest answer to what I wanted. Thank you